# Assign reward points on final custom order status update by admin from backend

Tags: reward-points, reward

I need to assign a `rewards point` after order final status (this is customized order status) update by admin. Also, the requirement to assign reward points on a % basis of custom order field in which value is filled by admin.

**For example:**

We are selling home services. Users can book service by ordering service as a normal product. But once final service delivery to the customer there is a service charge (differs from service to service) which added by admin into the custom field into order area and reward will calculate on the % basic of service charge.

Here I am not able to figure out how I manage the Reward assignment on order status update and custom field in order area on which reward will get calculated.

I really appreciate and Many thanks for reading my query.